# Ag-Grid in-react: how do I maintain row editing even when switching focus to a cell in another row?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in my react app to display data in a grid that needs to be editable. I have use-case to complete editing only when I click on a save button.

[Like in this example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcLTu.png)

I am able to implement stopEditing when save button is clicked, but the problem is that editing is also completed when any cell from different row is focused.

I tried to find a config to disable stopEditing when other cell is focused but without success.

Is there a way to keep editing a row in ag-grid after a cell from other row is focused?